# How to write mysql join sub query from 5 tables in laravel controller

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, query-builder

I have a MySQL query like bellow, and I want to use it in laravel controller,

I know how to use join in laravel, but I don't know how to write it when we have another sub query in the join statement,

```
SELECT barangs.id, barangs.kode_barang, barangs.nama_barang, 
IFNULL(a.QTY_IN,0) AS masuk, IFNULL(b.QTY_OUT,0) AS keluar, 
IFNULL(c.PO_RETUR_QTY,0) AS po_retur, IFNULL(d.CUS_RETUR_QTY,0) AS cus_retur, 
barangs.stok AS stok_akhir, barangs.harga_beli
FROM barangs 

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT barang_masuk_detail.id_barang, barang_masuk.tgl_masuk, SUM(barang_masuk_detail.qty_terima) AS QTY_IN
FROM barang_masuk
LEFT JOIN barang_masuk_detail ON barang_masuk.id = barang_masuk_detail.id_brg_masuk
/* WHERE barang_masuk.tgl_masuk BETWEEN "2015-08-01" AND "2015-08-31" */
GROUP BY barang_masuk_detail.id_barang ASC
)AS a ON a.id_barang = barangs.id

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT barang_keluar_detail.id_barang, barang_keluar.tgl_kirim, SUM(barang_keluar_detail.qty_dikirim) AS QTY_OUT
FROM barang_keluar
LEFT JOIN barang_keluar_detail ON barang_keluar.id = barang_keluar_detail.id_brg_keluar
/* WHERE barang_keluar.tgl_kirim BETWEEN "2015-08-01" AND "2015-08-31"*/
GROUP BY barang_keluar_detail.id_barang ASC
)AS b ON b.id_barang = barangs.id

/*join retur try */
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT retur_beli_detail.barang_id, retur_beli.tgl_retur, SUM(retur_beli_detail.retur_qty) AS PO_RETUR_QTY
FROM retur_beli
LEFT JOIN retur_beli_detail ON retur_beli.id = retur_beli_detail.retur_id
/* WHERE retur_beli.tgl_retur BETWEEN "2015-08-01" AND "2015-08-31"*/
GROUP BY retur_beli_detail.barang_id ASC
)AS c ON c.barang_id = barangs.id

/*join retur dari customer */
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT retur_kirim_detail.barang_id, retur_kirim.tgl_retur, SUM(retur_kirim_detail.retur_qty) AS CUS_RETUR_QTY
FROM retur_kirim
LEFT JOIN retur_kirim_detail ON retur_kirim.id = retur_kirim_detail.retur_id
/* WHERE retur_kirim.tgl_retur BETWEEN "2015-08-01" AND "2015-08-31"*/
GROUP BY retur_kirim_detail.barang_id ASC
)AS d ON d.barang_id = barangs.id
```

if I run in the sqlyog it works as expected, but not sure how to write it in laravel syntax,

[image]

oh if possible to filter it using whereBetween in laravel base on request send from user, where I need put the syntax ?

like whereBetween([ $request->startDate, $request->endDate ]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple way to execute query with below syntax:-

```
DB::select("select * from table JOIN ...");
```

This will provide you collection of filtered data.

**Edited Code**

to use `whereBetween()` Laravel where query you need to write MySQL query like below

```
$startDate = $request->startDate;
$endDate = $request->endDate;

DB::select("
    select * from table JOIN ... 
    where fieldName BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
");
```

To add more conditions, we need to write Plain MySQL query.

Comment: hi, thanks,
one more I want to in it filtered using where between, how I add that ?

like whereBetween([ $request->startDate, $request->endDate ]);

Comment: Hi thanks, I use " . $startDate . " before your comment, so I just need one quote and no dot to concate :D

you save my day, thank you :)